# Uploading new build of Rails app on AWS erases database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am a very new rails developer trying to get my app working on Amazon Web Services. I've gotten pretty far but have been having an issue for a while that I can't seem to solve. Let me know if more information is needed, sorry if I don't provide enough!

**THE PRIMARY ISSUE:**

Uploading a new build of the rails app onto AWS overwrites the existing AWS database.

**BACKGROUND:**

-The backend is built as a rails app. The github repository is located here:
https://github.com/JustinLennox/BloveitBackend

-I upload the backend to amazon web services and deploy it using their elastic beanstalk

-I add data (in the form of venues, users, etc.) to the backend on elastic beanstalk

-When I upload a new build of the app onto AWS, it erases all of the previous data (venues, users, etc.) that I'd added

**Possible cause of the problem:**
-I upload the rails app as a .zip file. I'm thinking this could be an issue (Picture below)
[image: Uploading the build to AWS]

Thank you again so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are creating the database as part of your Elastic Beanstalk environment.

The solution would be to use the AWS RDS service to create a database first and then just attach this database to your environment.

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html) should help.

Comment: Ok this sounds very promising and I had that exact thought. I did create an RDS database but is there a guide or something you could point me to for how to add data to it/attach it to my elastic environment?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps from [this](https://medium.com/@jatescher/how-to-set-up-a-rails-4-1-app-on-aws-with-elastic-beanstalk-and-postgresql-66d4e3412629#.26kfiset8) tutorial. Don't deploy your app as a zip rather use `git aws.push` after configuring beanstalk environment.

Comment: We have used the zip feature to deploy apps and the database has remained intact. I am not sure that is the problem.